# Object instancing is too slow in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instance

I'm making a painting program and started following [a tutorial](https://youtu.be/L51x0bRyoQQ) on YT. When I finished with the tutorials I reazlized that the instantiating was happening to slow and when I draged the brush really fast it would live gaps between the dots.

I have already tried lowering the script execution time in the project settings without any success.

```
public Transform baseDot;
public KeyCode mouseLeft;
public Vector2 mousePosition;
Vector2 mousePos;
Vector2 objPos;

void OnMouseOver()
{
    mousePos = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    objPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

    baseDot.position = mousePos;

    if (Input.GetKey(mouseLeft) )
        Instantiate(baseDot, objPos, baseDot.rotation);
}
```

Image of the problem:

[image]

I expect there to be no gaps and have a straight line resembling paint strokes

Comment: You're currently only instantiating a single dot each time a frame is rendered while the mouse is over the MonoBehaviour (a MonoBehaviour's `OnMouseOver` is only called at most once per rendering frame) .  If you want to instantiate more than one dot per frame, you'll probably want a loop that iterates over positions between the current mouse position and the mouse position from the last frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw multi-stroke lines in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429695/how-to-draw-multi-stroke-lines-in-unity) because instantiating a single gameobject per stroke is more efficient than instantiating many per frame