# How to add more points or position in linerenderer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a LineRenderer with only two points, start, and endpoints. I want to divide the line with a given number that will automatically create or add new points to the LineRenderer. For example, if I divide the line by 2, it will add another point in the center of LineRenderer.

**EDITED:**
Edited my question the second time now with the working script and image result. I don't know if this is the best solution but its working for me. The only thing that I don't know is how to compute the divisor to use based on the number of `line.position`. And for the duplicate flag. I think it's not the same as what I wanted.

```
GameObject stroke = new GameObject();
LineRenderer line = stroke.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
line.startWidth = 0.1f;
line.endWidth = 0.1f;
line.useWorldSpace = true;
float divisor;
Vector3 start = new Vector3(-6.7399,-0.2475,0);
Vector3 end = new Vector3(-3.742899, -0.2475, 0);

line.positionCount = 4;

if(line.position == 4)
    divisor = 0.333f; //get by 1/3
else if(line.position == 3)
    divisor = 0.5f; //get by 1/2

Vector3 valuePerPosition = Vector3.Lerp(start, end, divisor);

for (int i = 0; i < line.positionCount; i++)
{
    Vector3 newPosition = start - valuePerPosition;
    line.SetPosition(i, start - (newPosition * i));

    GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
    sphere.transform.position = start - (newPosition * i);
    sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.125f, 0.125f, 0.125f);
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429695/how-to-draw-multi-stroke-lines-in-unity

Comment: @derHugo This is definitely not a duplicate of that. --- A multi-stroke (multi-line) is not the same as a segmented single line.

Comment: @unice - You can increase or decrease the number of positions with [`LineRenderer.positionCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-positionCount.html), and then set the positions with [`LineRenderer.SetPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPosition.html)

Comment: @XenoRo - Yes, but my problem is how to divide the total length of  linerenderer and create a point at that position. I've edidted my question and added sample script and image.

Comment: @derHugo this question would really benefit from an example or explanation of how to use `Vector3.Lerp`. Voting to reopen

Comment: @unice - Your for-loop code doesn't make much sense, unless `end` is an offset rather than a point. But leaving that aside, your code seems to be working, just not coded for what you intend it. --- If `divisor = 3`, `end = Vector3(4, 4, 0)`, and `mid = end / divisor` then `mid = Vector3(1.33~, 1.33~, 0)` (I'll shorten to "V(1.33)" henceforth)... Then, in the loop, `(mid * i)` equals `i = 0 = V(1.33*0) = V(0)`, `i = 1 = V(1.33*1) = V(1.33)`, `i = 2 = V(1.33*2) = V(2.66)` and so forth. Exactly what your inspector shows.

Comment: @XenoRo Yes it does't make sense haha, just showing an example of what I want to accomplish. But I updated it again using vector3.lerp as Ruzihm mentioned above.